# Find and replace a word in all the files, which is falling under a searching criteria at Unix

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, find

I want to replace a word in all the files inside all the sub directories, which satisfy some criteria.

Below is the elaborated situation.

> I have to replace all the Word having case insensitive word like
>   {classy, CLASSY, cLassy ,..} to word "Vintage". Also I only need to
>   replace it where it have a case insensitive word "insert" or "INSERT".

So if i have 2 files having below content.

```
File1.txt
asd asdsd INSERT asdasd classy
asddsdff sdf sdff sdf  CLASSY
sfre asfert asdd asd insert asdgweg 
qwe asfer wrererw  werer wewer INSERT CLassy


File2.txt
fhfgh asdsd insert asdasd ClASSY
asddsdff dfg  sdff sdf  CLASSY
sdgg asfert dfg asd insert asdgweg CLASSY
qwe asfer wrererw  werer wewer INSERT
```

**I want to change the content of both the file as**

```
File1.txt
asd asdsd INSERT asdasd Vintage
asddsdff sdf sdff sdf  CLASSY
sfre asfert asdd asd insert asdgweg 
qwe asfer wrererw  werer wewer INSERT Vintage

File2.txt
fhfgh asdsd insert asdasd Vintage
asddsdff dfg  sdff sdf  CLASSY
sdgg asfert dfg asd insert asdgweg Vintage
qwe asfer wrererw  werer wewer INSERT
```

Below is the command I used , but it is not working fine. Can you please help me understand the issue.

```
find /rootFolderPath -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i insert -exec sed -i -e 'classy/Vintage/I' -- {} +
```

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry it was a typo..  I have fixed it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `gnu-sed` with `find` as:

```
cd /rootFolderPath
find . -name '*.txt' -exec \
     sed -i '/\binsert\b/I{s/\bclassy\b/Vintage/gI;}' {} +
```

Here is what `sed` command does:

- `-i`: Inline editing
- `/\binsert\b/I`: Search string `insert` in a line (case insensitive for `I` and `\b` for word boundaries)
- `{s/\bclassy\b/Vintage/gI;}`: If `insert` is found in a line then substitute `classy` with `Vintage` (again \b`is for word boundaries,`I`is for case insensitive and`g` is for global search)

Comment: i will really appreciate if you can explain me 

sed -i '/insert/I{s/classy/Vintage/gI;}'

Comment: Added explanation in my answer.

Comment: Good point @EdMorton. I have added word boundaries in the answer.

Comment: Can you please also help me understand on why it is not working when using with  "xargs"
find /rootFolderPath -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i insert

Comment: I don't even have `grep` in my answer.

Comment: Hi @anubhava .. no I mean when I was using xargs grep ..why did it not worked.. any particular reason for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168762/discussion-between-arpan-and-anubhava).